# Manual network IP leads to spotty connection

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, router, network-bridge

I'm running 14.04 via VirtualBoxVM with my network in Bridged mode. DHCP works great, setting a manual address used to work fine but today it's acting up.

**DHCP values:**

- IP: 192.168.1.8
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS: 192.168.1.1

**Manual values:**

- IP: 192.168.1.200
- Netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS: 192.168.1.1

I can `ping google.com` in both scenarios. With DHCP I `ping` infinitely for < 3ms. With a *manual* IP I get two quick `ping`s of < 3ms then I get a ping for 2k ms which takes closer to 30 seconds to receive, this process repeats over and over.

Also, I've noticed can `ping` devices on the same network as expected but when I ping my gateway it acts the same way a `ping` to google.com does. I've restarted my router (gateway) and computer a number of times trying to figure out what's going on.

What's going on and how can I fix it while keeping a manual address?

**Ping example with gateway:**

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9371 ttl=64 time=2.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9372 ttl=64 time=1.90 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9402 ttl=64 time=1116 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9403 ttl=64 time=108 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9404 ttl=64 time=1.17 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9405 ttl=64 time=554 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9406 ttl=64 time=2.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9407 ttl=64 time=0.828 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9408 ttl=64 time=1.17 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9409 ttl=64 time=2.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9433 ttl=64 time=1583 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9434 ttl=64 time=582 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9435 ttl=64 time=2.19 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9436 ttl=64 time=1.94 ms
```

**Ping example with Google.com:**

```
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9535 ttl=59 time=4.03 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9536 ttl=59 time=4.36 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9537 ttl=59 time=3703 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9538 ttl=59 time=2703 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9539 ttl=59 time=1704 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9540 ttl=59 time=704 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9541 ttl=59 time=3.77 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9542 ttl=59 time=3.80 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9587 ttl=59 time=985 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9588 ttl=59 time=3.84 ms
64 bytes from 216-21-170-20.mci.googlefiber.net (216.21.170.20): icmp_seq=9589 ttl=59 time=3.96 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test and found that if I manually change the IP to the same IP the `DHCP` gives then my connection is fine. I added 1 to the IP and it was still fine. I went close to my desired IP and it was still fine. Once I use `192.168.1.200` I get the same issues.

**Current Solution**

The IP in question has been manually "leased" by the router router before. I say "leased" because it was manually done but is still one record. Anyway, I suspect this causes a hiccup on the router's IP tables so I've decided to use a different IP in the mean time instead of figure out how to clear the IP tables on my router.

**Cheers!**